# Get path to file using bash parameter expansion

Tags: bash, path

Given a path to a file let say: **/home/user1/archive.zip**

Can someone tell me how can I remove the string **archive.zip** without using external binaries?

I know that:

```
${Path2File##*/}
```

Can give me the file name but I need the folder path for this one.

A guide to wildcard understanding or an explanation is welcomed as well.

Comment: try "dirname PATH"

Comment: Nice one! I can manage for now until the question is answered! Thank you

Comment: @DarkXDroid : You could use parameter expansion itself. See my answer on how to.

Comment: @nouseforname "without external binaries", which would include `dirname`.

Comment: So dirname is part of the bash interpreter? I didn't know. I want to make my code compatible with cygwin and this info is useful too. Thanks

Comment: @DarkXDroid There are bash [\[ builtins \]](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Builtins.html) but `dirname` is not one of them.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Do

```
"${Path2File%\/*}"
```

or using external binaries

```
dirname "$Path2File" # Not desirable as you've mentioned already
```

---

**Notes:**

1. In the shell parameter expansion of type `${parameter%word}`, the word is expanded to produce a pattern just as in filename expansion. If the pattern matches a trailing portion of the expanded value of parameter, then the result of the expansion is the value of parameter with the shortest matching pattern deleted.
2. Since the `/` has special meaning in shell parameter expansion we just escaped it ie `\/`. The intention is to match the file basename  ie
   `/example.zip` in `/path/to/example.zip` and delete it.

**Reference:**

Shell [[ Parameter Expansion ]](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html)

Comment: Great! I love the first solution... Just what I wanted. Many thanks for the explanation

Comment: I will! Now I understand that you actually need to deleted the last portion first in order to filter and get the data you need. It's clear now

Comment: `/` only has special meaning when used with the substring replacement operator. Following `%`, it is treated normally and does not need to be escaped.

Comment: @chepner : Thankyou. But is there a harm doing so here?

Comment: Nope; the backslash just tends to obfuscate the string a little. Escaped characters with no special meaning just expand to themselves.

Comment: @chepner Okay. I agree.. I hope the op will see your point when he go thru the comments.

Comment: @chepner Alright so it's only for better readability? Thanks for your concern on my question. I'll proceed with your instruction

Answer (score 4):

The `*` wildcard means any character will match. The `##` is removing the longest matching pattern from the parameter. For example:

```
$ a=/path/to/file
$ echo ${a##*t}
o/file
```

In this example, we said delete everything up to and including `t`. It removed the `/pat` as you would expect, but as it found a second `t` it kept going. (A single `#` would stop at the first `t`).

A more useful example is to remove the path, as you have done, by matching up to and including the last `/`.

```
$ echo ${a##*/}
file
```

The `%` matches at the end of the string.

```
$ echo ${a%/*}
/path/to
```

This means delete from the **rightmost** slash `/` and everything else `*`.

The single `%` looks for the shortest possible match. If we use `%%` the match keeps looking all the way back to the start of the string and matches on the first character `/` and gobbles the lot.

Comment: I like this explanation and the command is better for readability purpose. I'll experiment with your examples! Many thanks for your time sir

Comment: You are very welcome. I was having trouble articulating what I wanted to say, so am glad you found some value in it.

Comment: I know! It's quite difficult to articulate as you mention but your explanation is better in order to replace the "cut", "grep", "tr", "awk" binaries for simple string manipulation. To my understanding this is faster. Thanks again