# How to get basename of parent's parent's directory name in shell?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I want to get hold of the basename of the parent directory of the parent directory of the current directory in a shell script.

For example:

```
$ pwd
/home/tmp/terminal/env/1239754/control/state
$
```

I want to get this - `1239754`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get path to file using bash parameter expansion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38034634/get-path-to-file-using-bash-parameter-expansion)

Comment: Do you want the basename of the parent of the current working directory, or the basename of the parent of the directory containing the link through which the script is invoked, or the basename of the current working directory of the parent process of the process running the script?

Comment: @WilliamPursell. I want basename of parent's parent's parent where script is running.

Comment: With `bash` and `awk`. Use `/` as field separator and output the third last field: `awk -F '/' '{print $(NF-2)}' <<< "$PWD"`

Answer (score 24):

I suggest to use `basename` and `dirname`:

```
basename $(dirname $(dirname "$PWD"))
```

Comment: Could use `"${PWD%/*}"` instead of `$(dirname "$PWD")`

Comment: @123: yes, that is possibe, too.

Comment: @cyrus @ 123. Thank you, both seem to work :)

Could you share how to I go another level up?

ex - pwd /home/tmp/terminal/env/1239754/control/state

I want to get this - 1239754.

Comment: @Insanitee: I‘ve fixed my bug.

Comment: Note that for eccentric values of `$PWD`, you can run into problems: `basename $(dirname $(dirname "/Users/Me/ spaced out/ man kind / noxiousness / oblivion"))`.  You fix that by enclosing each `$(…)` in double quotes: `basename "$(dirname "$(dirname "/Users/Me/ spaced out/ man kind / noxiousness / oblivion")")"`.  That yields `□man□kind□` (where I've been reduced to using `□` to indicate spaces in comment MarkDown).

Answer (score 6):

Based on Cyrus and 123's suggestions, this is probably the simplest solution, also worked on unicode characters. Just have to add one more /*

```
basename ${PWD%/*/*}
```

output:

```
1239754
```

Answer (score 2):

you can try this

```
basename `cd ../..; pwd`
```